# CF_WKHTMLTOPDF setting page size to Envelope

Tags: coldfusion, wkhtmltopdf, coldfusion-2018

I am using WKHTMLTOPDF in ColdFusion 18 and am trying to have the page size be "Envelope DL". I found the global setting size.PageSize so in the code below I added `pagesize = "Envelope DL"` but this did not change it. Does anyone have any other ideas or could tell me what I am missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<CF_WKHTMLTOPDF
    PageURL = "http://www.com/temppdf/test.htm"
    filename = "D://temppdf/test.pdf"
    orientation = "portrait"
    DisableSmartShrinking="yes"
    margintop = "0.25"
    marginleft = "0.25"
    marginright = "0.25"
    marginbottom = "0.25"
    TimeOut = "180"
    AddFooterPageNum="yes">

<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="inline; filename=""CS_#Dateformat(NOW(),'MMDDYYYY')#.pdf""">
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="D://temppdf/test.pdf" deletefile="Yes">
```

Comment: Is wkhtmltopdf a custom tag or is it an external `.exe`

Comment: @JamesAMohler wkhtmltopdf is an external `.exe` that's installed on the application server.  His code example is confusing because he's calling it through both a custom tag and direct command line execution via `<cfexecute>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote the [ColdFusion WKHTMLTOPDF custom tag](https://gist.github.com/JamoCA/74e556e7d4f1a715a41d). If you look at the source code, the notes indicate where to look for the "pagesize" parameter.

Here are the allowable paper sizes. (I've used "Comm10E" for my envelopes):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qprinter.html#PaperSize-enum

```
QPrinter::A0    5   841 x 1189 mm
QPrinter::A1    6   594 x 841 mm
QPrinter::A2    7   420 x 594 mm
QPrinter::A3    8   297 x 420 mm
QPrinter::A4    0   210 x 297 mm, 8.26 x 11.69 inches
QPrinter::A5    9   148 x 210 mm
QPrinter::A6    10  105 x 148 mm
QPrinter::A7    11  74 x 105 mm
QPrinter::A8    12  52 x 74 mm
QPrinter::A9    13  37 x 52 mm
QPrinter::B0    14  1000 x 1414 mm
QPrinter::B1    15  707 x 1000 mm
QPrinter::B2    17  500 x 707 mm
QPrinter::B3    18  353 x 500 mm
QPrinter::B4    19  250 x 353 mm
QPrinter::B5    1   176 x 250 mm, 6.93 x 9.84 inches
QPrinter::B6    20  125 x 176 mm
QPrinter::B7    21  88 x 125 mm
QPrinter::B8    22  62 x 88 mm
QPrinter::B9    23  33 x 62 mm
QPrinter::B10   16  31 x 44 mm
QPrinter::C5E   24  163 x 229 mm
QPrinter::Comm10E   25  105 x 241 mm, U.S. Common 10 Envelope
QPrinter::DLE   26  110 x 220 mm
QPrinter::Executive 4   7.5 x 10 inches, 190.5 x 254 mm
QPrinter::Folio 27  210 x 330 mm
QPrinter::Ledger    28  431.8 x 279.4 mm
QPrinter::Legal 3   8.5 x 14 inches, 215.9 x 355.6 mm
QPrinter::Letter    2   8.5 x 11 inches, 215.9 x 279.4 mm
QPrinter::Tabloid   29  279.4 x 431.8 mm
QPrinter::Custom    30  Unknown, or a user defined size.
```

Comment: Hey James does it have an automatic print feature?

Comment: Like instead of the preview that pops up is it possible to have it just start printing?

Comment: in chrome that is

Comment: Not that I know of.  I once used a javascript-based technique that do this, but I don't think it works anymore. When dynamically generating PDFs, I usually force a download and/or store was a statically-generated PDF file.  Chrome 77 disabled auto-print. Here's a Chrome plugin, but your mileage may vary: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-direct-print/fnfkcaeloalplnglklappfjfjeafakeo?hl=en-US

What is your actually need?  (You could set up a sub-directory that auto-prints any recently saved PDF files.)

Comment: awesome thanks for helping me for what I should look for

Comment: This is what finally worked for me to set the size for #10 envelopes using barryvdh/laravel-snappy with loadView().

Answer (score 2):

According to the wkhtmltopdf manual located [here](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt) it then refers you to list of usable `--page-size` options which can be found [here](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qprinter.html#PaperSize-enum).

The page size of "DL Envelope" is 110mm x 220mm.  So the page size option you need to supply to wkhtmltopdf is `--page-size DLE`.

Comment: @DavidBrierton your code example is confusing.  Are you direct executing `wkhtmltopdf` via command line using `<cfexecute>` or are you calling it through a custom tag using `<CF_WKHTMLTOPDF>`?

Comment: @DavidBrierton  Being that you're defining your page attributes in the custom tag, then yes add it there.  Then inside the custom tag, pass that parameter into the `<cfexecute>` as an argument as I'm presuming all the other arguments are coded that way.